# IMEI using Javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, nokia

is there any way to retrieve the IMEI number of a cellphone, using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

No, javascript running on the mobile's browser can't access this information.

You could do it with Java (inside a Midlet), but this is device dependent and isn't available for all manufacturers.

Comment: Could you please comment on this article:
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Retrieving_IMEI_in_WRT

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Nokia's Web Runtime Technology that allows you to do so. Anyway this only runs on Nokia phones. I don't expect to find something similar for other phones.

Comment: kgiannakakis,
can you show me how a WRT script can be embedded in a webpage?